# From argwhere to where?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a fast way of getting the output of argwhere in the output of where format ?

Let me show you what I'm doing with a bit of code:

```
In [123]: filter = np.where(scores[:,:,:,4,:] > 21000)

In [124]: filter
Out[124]: 
(array([ 2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23]),
 array([13, 13,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5]),
 array([0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
 array([44, 44,  0,  1,  2,  3,  6,  8, 12, 14, 22, 31, 58, 76, 82, 41]))

In [125]: filter2 = np.argwhere(scores[:,:,:,4,:] > 21000)

In [126]: filter2
Out[126]: 
array([[ 2, 13,  0, 44],
       [ 2, 13,  1, 44],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  1],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  2],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  6],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  8],
       [ 4,  4,  3, 12],
       [ 4,  4,  3, 14],
       [ 4,  4,  3, 22],
       [23,  4,  2, 31],
       [23,  4,  2, 58],
       [23,  4,  2, 76],
       [23,  4,  2, 82],
       [23,  5,  2, 41]])

In [150]: scores[:,:,:,4,:][filter]
Out[150]: 
array([ 21344.,  21344.,  24672.,  24672.,  24672.,  24672.,  25232.,
        25232.,  25232.,  25232.,  24672.,  21152.,  21152.,  21152.,
        21152.,  21344.], dtype=float16)

In [129]: filter2[np.argsort(scores[:,:,:,4,:][filter])]
Out[129]: 
array([[23,  4,  2, 31],
       [23,  4,  2, 58],
       [23,  4,  2, 76],
       [23,  4,  2, 82],
       [ 2, 13,  0, 44],
       [ 2, 13,  1, 44],
       [23,  5,  2, 41],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  1],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  2],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  3, 22],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  6],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  8],
       [ 4,  4,  3, 12],
       [ 4,  4,  3, 14]])
```

`129` is my desired output, so my code works, but I'm trying to make it as fast as possible. Should I get `filter2` with `np.array(filter).transpose()` ? Is there something even better ?

Edit, trying to put it more clearly: I want a list of indices ordered by the value they return when applied to an array. To do that, I need both the output of np.where and np.argwhere, and I'm wondering what is the fastest way to switch from one output to the other, or if there's another of getting my result.

Comment: Maybe take a sample `scores` and explain what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the code for `argwhere`:

```
return transpose(asanyarray(a).nonzero())
```

while `where` docs say:

> where(condition, [x, y])
>   If only `condition` is given, return `condition.nonzero()`.

In effect, both use `a.nonzero()`.  One uses it as is, the other transposes it.

```
In [933]: x=np.zeros((2,3),int)
In [934]: x[[0,1,0],[0,1,2]]=1
In [935]: x
Out[935]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])

In [936]: x.nonzero()
Out[936]: (array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([0, 2, 1], dtype=int32))
In [937]: np.where(x)   # same as nonzero()
Out[937]: (array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([0, 2, 1], dtype=int32))
In [938]: np.argwhere(x)
Out[938]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int32)
In [939]: np.argwhere(x).T
Out[939]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

`argwhere().T` is the same as `where` except in a 2d rather than a tuple.

`np.transpose(filter)` and `np.array(filter).T` look equally good.  For a large array the time spent in `nonzero` is much larger than the time spent on these transformations.